# How to handle System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, comexception

I am developing a Windows application where I manipulate Word Application. More specific, I am opening a Word Document but when I quit it and try to open another Word Document this Error comes out.

How to handle

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) at Microsoft.Office,Word.ApplicationClass.set_Visible(Boolean Prop)**

If I don't quit the Word Application this error does not come out.

Below I show you the functions that I open and quit the Word Application.

```
    //function to open word Document located in a specific path
        public static void openWordDocument(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                wordApplication.Visible = true;
                string filePath = myPath + fileName;
                WordApi.Document docx = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }



//function to quit wordApplication 
  public static void CloseWordApp() {

            try {
                Object wordAppObject = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
                WordApi.Application wordApp = (WordApi.Application)wordAppObject;  //cast Object to its actual type
                wordApp.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                 MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Why are you using the ROT for `Word.Application` when you have perfectly good `wordApplication` field?  Also you could end up getting the wrong instance.  Just use that field and perform a `wordApplication.Quit();  wordApplication = null;`.  I wouldn't worry about that last link you mentioned, can't see how it applies here

Comment: Did not work. Still get the exact same error. @MickyD

Comment: Think about the sequence you described in the statement: "I am opening a Word Document but when I quit it and try to open another Word Document this Error comes out." The way I interpret your sequence is that you are trying to use a **closed** Word application to open a new document. Also doing this with `static` instances is asking for trouble as unless you specifically null those instances, they are not eligible for the GC to collect and release the underlying COM reference.

Comment: Hang on, where are you actually initialising `wordApplication`??  In one part of the code you are using a field and another the ROT.  When you quit Word you need to set `wordApplication` to `null`.  You’ll need to recreate it later before using it

Comment: By the way, you can use `dynamic` variables with COM instead of casting; having to know the type; or add references to interop and/or COM libraries.  You won’t get IntelliSense though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out what is the problem.
The main problem was that when I quit it and try to open another Word Document,which opening another Word Document means get/create an Object of Word Application. In my case `wordApp != null`, after finalizing the application, so I had to create another **Word Application Object** and return it for the case.

```
  //open word Document located in a specific path
    public static void openWordDocument(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            wordApplication = createWordApplicationObject(wordApplication);
            wordApplication.Visible = true;
            string filePath = myPath + fileName;
            WordApi.Document docx = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
private static WordApi.Application createWordApplicationObject(WordApi.Application wordApp)
    {
        WordApi.Application wordAppFirstTime;
        WordApi.Application wordApp1;
        if (wordApp == null)
        {
            wordAppFirstTime = new WordApi.Application();
            return wordAppFirstTime;

        }
        else
        {
            wordApp1 = new WordApi.Application();
            return wordApp1;
        }

    }
```

With **CloseWordApp()** remain the same.

Comment: Sharing your answer to your own question is appreciated as positive contribution to the community.

Comment: I hope it will help someone, someday.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the exception is fired by the following line of code:

```
wordApplication.Visible = true;
```

You need to make sure the COM server is alive. Because after quitting the object becomes unavailable. I'd suggest setting such object references to null, so later we could check whether the application object is still alive. For example:

```
try
{
    if (wordApplication == null)
    {
        wordApplication = new Word.Application();
    }
    wordApplication.Visible = true;
    string filePath = myPath + fileName;
    WordApi.Document docx = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Good.  I didn’t even notice at first OP was using orphaned fields. +1

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a solution that works for me. We had this issue in a .net web service, along with other errors, like "the remote procedure call failed" on Word.Documents.Open(). i'll list all the things we tried, and finish with the solution.
**we tried:**

- Make sure RPC service is up.  Word is not corrupted, opens properly,
  including the file we were opening.
- restart server and service hosting the web application.
- Rollback a windows update that occured the same day it stopped working.
- Uninstalled the antivirus software.
- We isolated the code to a third party app to validate it was the open()
  method that caused the problem, and using different files as well. We
  created a win form app, and consol app. We ran that small  app as win
  admin, a regular account as well as the account that runs the web
  app.
- We ran procMon.
- we did a repair on word.
- we installed Office all  over, we tried 32 and 64bits version

**Finale solution:**
we deleted the user profile that runs the web app.

4 days to find that out. I'd thought i'd share my paine with the world. lol

while posting these lines, we are not sure why the local profile created this issue.

Comment: i just want to add the web app runs on a windows server 2012 with office 2010, and upgrading to 365 was not a viable solution with the time we had. We did notice that the error didnt seem to occur with office 365 on windows 10.